# create(mutate) column with a condition of another one

Tags: r, conditional-statements, create-table, dplyr, mutated

I have this data

> ```
>      COL
>     AABC1
>    AAAABD2
>   AAAAAABF3
> ```

I would like to make a certain column like this:

> ```
>      COL         NEW_COL
>     AABC1          T1
>    AAAABD2         T2
>   AAAAAABF3        T3
> ```

If COL contains 'BC', NEW_COL will be T1

contains 'BD', it will be T2

contains 'BF', it will be T3.

I would like to use mutate and grepl function but I have 80 conditions (like BC>T1) so that the code does not work in the R.

With the table like:

> ```
>     CLASS       NEW_COL
>     BC          T1
>     BD          T2
>     BF          T3
> ```

Could I use mutate(create) new column with above standard table ??

Comment: You can use mutate to create a new column, but it sounds like you will need to write a function to get the values you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your data:

```
DF <- data.frame(COL = c("AABC1",
                         "AAAABD2",
                         "AAAAABF3"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lookup_tbl <- data.frame(CLASS = c("BC", "BD", "BF"),
                         NEW_COL = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Your problem is solved by a join, after some initial preparation.

To prepare `DF`, you need to add a column that extracts any instance of `CLASS` in the lookup table from `COL` in `DF`. Then you can join normally. In R:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>%
  mutate(CLASS = gsub(paste0("^.*(", 
                            paste0(lookup_tbl[["CLASS"]], collapse = "|"),
                            ").*$"), 
                      "\\1",
                      lookup_tbl[["CLASS"]])) %>%
  # or inner_join as required
  left_join(lookup_tbl, by = "CLASS")
```

How the solution should behave `COL` matches zero or more than one instance in `CLASS` will need to be specified. The above handles both cases, but maybe not how you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup table with your 80 conditions and write a little function to match against it. Here's an example (normally, you'd read in `lookup_table` from file, I'm guessing):

```
library(tidyverse)

lookup_table <- data.frame(
                    row.names = c('BC', 'BD', 'BF'), 
                    new_col = c('T1', 'T2', 'T3'), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lookup <- function(x, table) {
    for (class in rownames(table)) {
        if (grepl(class, x)) {
            return(table[class, 'new_col'])
        }
    }
}

data_frame(col = c('AABC1', 'AAAABD2', 'AAAAAABF3')) %>% 
    rowwise %>% mutate(new_col = lookup(col, lookup_table))
```

Note that this will take the first match it finds, so be sure your lookup table is ordered properly with respect to the priority you want to give the matching rules.